# What does this C function do?

Tags: c, function

```
double *f(int n, double v)
{
  double *a, *p;
  a = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
  if (a != NULL)
    for (p = a; p < a + n; p++)
      *p = v;
  return a;
}
```

Can you explain me what this function is needed for? Does it copy the content of v in n? If yes, why does it return a? I really don't get it... Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion I suggest to study little bit more C before ask these kind of questions. best wishes!

Comment: There are an infinite number of C functions that one (who obviously knows NOTHING about C) might not understand ... why not just post all of them to SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double *f(int n, double v) 
{
  double *a, *p;
  a = malloc(n * sizeof(double));  // allocate memory enough for "n" doubles (an array)
  if (a != NULL)                   // if the allocation was successful
    for (p = a; p < a + n; p++)    // loop from the beginning of the array to the end
      *p = v;                // fill every element of the array with the value "v"
  return a;                  // return the new array
}
```

So if I called this function:

```
double * myarray;
myarray = f(3, 1.3);
```

Now I have:

```
myarray[0] = 1.3
myarray[1] = 1.3
myarray[2] = 1.3
```

So to answers your questions:

> Can you explain me what this function is needed for?

- allocates and initializes an array of doubles.

> Does it copy the content of v in n?

- No. Considering `v` is a double and `n` is an int, that doesn't even make sense. It makes an array `n` large and initializes it with the value `v`.

> If yes, why does it return a?

- It returns `a` so you have a reference to the newly created array. (see example above on how it could be used)

Answer (score 6):

It returns a newly allocated `double` array of size `n` filled with value `v`, or `NULL` if the allocation fails.

This loop:

```
for (p = a; p < a + n; p++)
    *p = v;
```

uses pointer arithmetic. As `p` is a pointer to a `double`, incrementing it will point to the next double to write. `*p = v` writes the double at the specified location.

Answer (score 3):

It allocates an array of `n` doubles, initialising each element of the array to the value of `v`.

The function returns `a` to allow the caller to use this newly allocated array.

Answer (score 1):

It allocs a memory area of `n * sizeof(double)` bytes and enterely fill it with `v` value

Comment: This is a bit misleading, since it makes it sound as if `v` is a byte, which it really isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate an array of n doubles in heap, fill it with v and return the pointer to it?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the `v` n times into an array of float

The array is allocated in the function and contains `n` float elements.

at the end of the function each element in the array `a` is containing `v` as value